# HTML 5 + iOS - creating hybrid applications

Tags: ios, html, jquery-mobile, cordova, hybrid

I am trying to convert my native iOS app into a hybrid app using HTML 5.
After doing a research I ended up with **jQuery mobile + phoneGap.**

My questions are

1. Is it possible to mix html 5 and native iOS features within a single
   view? For example can I use html text field to get the value and use
   it to do some conversion using iOS picker.
2. Is it possible to  navigate to a native xib from an html page?
3. And finally is there any better solution to create a hybrid app?

thanks in advance

Comment: 1 - Possible, but iOS features will be on top of the web view 2 - Possible, but you have to make sure that the web view is not unload

Comment: @nhahtdh thanks for the reply.
can u suggest me some tutorials on the above topics.

Comment: Check whether there is existing plugins that you can use or modify. Otherwise, I think you have to write your own plugin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Yes, you can mix native iOS features within a single 'view'. If you're looking to insert a native iOS picker *into* the web view, that's not really possible. As nhahtdh mentioned, any native iOS views you add will be placed on top of your HTML5 UIWebView. To perform tasks like this, you'll need to master communication via Javascript. See frameworks like https://github.com/diy/conduit for techniques on how to easily communicate between ObjC and Javascript to pass values back and forth between native and HTML.
2. It is possible to perform navigations from HTML pages (when clicking on links, for example), by setting up your iOS app to watch for specific URL requests, and perform some action based on them. I've used the NSURLCache for this purpose. So, if you wanted a link in your HTML to trigger a load of a xib file, you can watch for that URL to be requested via the NSURLCache, and load your xib when you see it. [This link](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/09/substituting-local-data-for-remote.html) helped me master this technique.
3. It is my understanding that all of the hybrid iOS + HTML frameworks use this general technique of establishing a REST-like set of URL requests that can be parsed out by a NSURLCache-like system and trigger native events based on those URLs. While using an existing framework may save you some time, it's not that difficult to implement yourself for more simple functionality. The big frameworks might help you along with more advanced caching of the HTML resources, however.

Comment: For 2), you can also extend the delegate function of UIWebView and define your own protocol to signal load of xib (which is the same as what Cordova does internally) .

Comment: can I use childBrowser plugin to load xib into the app?

Answer (score 1):

May be i am late here but first two question's answer is **YES** you can. You can call Objective C method which has a Picker displaying codes and Navigating/pushing other Views, from your web having Javascript. You just need to track them in your native app using UIWebViewDelegate. Here's example how i did this :

// In Your Javascript file, inside the method from where you want to invoke Pickerview or want to push another native view

```
       var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
       iframe.setAttribute("src", "js-frame:myObjectiveCFunction"; 
      document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
       iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
       iframe = null;
```

In your Native Objective - C file : include <<**UIWebViewDelegate**>>

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView  shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
       navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

if ([[[request URL] absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"js-frame:"]) {
    // Extract the selector name from the URL
    NSArray *components = [requestString componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
    NSString *functionName = [components objectAtIndex:1];
    // Call the given selector
    [self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(functionName)];
    // Cancel the location change
    return NO;
}
// Accept this location change
return YES;
```

}

```
- (void)myObjectiveCFunction {
    // Do whatever you want!
   // show Native picker view
   // Push another native View
}
```

In the same way , you can even send the parameters from HTML page to Objective c. 
    // -----------------------------------

Comment: Hey I am new to iOS. And as novice I have given the task to create a hybrid app. I generally work in Android. For Hybrid Android I make the HTML files, JS and CSS files, put it into folders and call the html file from a container. In this case that is in iOS, can you tell me where can I put the HTML files and call me. If you have any demo can you please show me?